# With what speed must e.g. a car drive into a turn so it won't drift out?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

> I am trying to figure out the following question: with what speed must e.g. a car drive into a turn  so it won't drift out (if a turn is a circumference of a semicircle)?

e.g. $r= 5 m$

$a_r= w^2 \cdot r$ and $v=w \cdot r$

How far can I make up the data? I already set $r$ to $5 m$. I cannot make up a value for $a_r$ or $w$ or (of course) $v$.

How can I calculate this with only $r$?
Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of a force, either friction, or gravity (if the road is slanted for instance) to account for the "forces" side of the 2nd Newton law:
$$
\sum\vec{F}=m\vec{a}
$$
Whereas the Right Hand Side (RHS) should contain the centripetal acceleration, i.e.:
$$
m\vec{a}=-m\frac{v^2}{r}\hat{r}
$$
And the minus means it is directed towards the center of the circle.

Try and see which forces are you working with...
again, these traditionally might be friction, gravity,some kind of tension (if the car is pulled in by Spiderman's webs or something)

Comment: What is $\hat{r}$?

Comment: That is a vector notation, a "hat" over a vector means a vector with a length of 1.
Which means that you can use it to note simply a direction.
In this case it means the radial direction. i.e. the direction from the center of the circle, to a point on the circumference